# Rails: Finding a deeply nested association with a where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have two models joined with a has_many :through relationship:

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :publication_contributors
  has_many :contributors, :through => :publication_contributors
end

class Contributor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :publication_contributors
  has_many :publications, :through => :publication_contributors
end

class PublicationContributor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :publication
  belongs_to :contributor
end
```

(Something unusual and important about my PublicationContributor model is that it has more than just a pair of database ids, it also has a string attribute called contributor_type. This string could contain roles such as "Author" or "Translator" or "Publisher". I don't believe this is the problem here, but a solution must still account for it.)

I want to find a Publication that has specific contributors like so:

```
Publication
  .joins(:publication_contributors =>  :contributor)
  .where(:publication_contributors => 
            {:contributor_type => "Author", 
             :contributor => {:name => params[:authors]}})
```

Everything works fine until I get to the nested :contributor, at which point the SQL sputters:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'publication_contributors.contributor' in 'where clause'
```

Rather than looking for publication_contributors.contributor_id, it's looking for publication_contributors.contributor, which doesn't exist. Am I doing something wrong in my code? I can't find any other examples of a where clause with deeply nested associations like this. Perhaps it's not even possible?

UPDATE:

The generated SQL

```
←[1m←[35mPublication Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `publications`.* FROM `publicati
ons` INNER JOIN `publication_contributors` ON `publication_contributors`.`public
ation_id` = `publications`.`id` INNER JOIN `contributors` ON `contributors`.`id`
 = `publication_contributors`.`contributor_id` WHERE `publication_contributors`.
`contributor_type` = 'Author' AND `publication_contributors`.`contributor` = '--
-\n:name:\n- Marilynne Robinson\n' LIMIT 1
```

Also, I have this association in my Publications model:

```
has_many :authors, :through => :publication_contributors, :source => :contributor, :conditions => {:publication_contributors => {:contributor_type => "Author"}}
```

I was thinking that I could do this:

```
Publication.joins(:authors).where(:authors => {:name => params[:authors]})
```

But that throws the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'authors.name' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL query please?

Comment: I assume by "Author" you mean "Contributor" in your update?

Comment: No, I mean authors. Although they aren't a model and don't have a database table, I've still made an ActiveRecord association by that name which finds contributors which have the contributor_type "Author."

Answer (score 49, accepted):

try to change your where clause :

```
Publication
  .joins( :publication_contributors => :contributor )
  .where( :publication_contributors => {:contributor_type => "Author"}, 
          :contributors             => {:name => params[:authors]} )
```

ActiveRecord api is not extremely consistent here : the arguments for `where` do not work exactly as those for `joins`. This is because the arguments for `joins` do *not* reflect the underlying SQL, whereas the arguments for `where` do.

`where` accepts an hash whose keys are **table names**, and values are hashes (that themselves have column names as keys). It just prevents ambiguity when targetting a column that has the same name in two tables.

This also explains why your second problem arises : the relation `authors` does not exist.

Comment: That was it! This solution is far simpler than what I was imagining I'd have to do. Thanks for saving me a lot of time.

Comment: you're welcome. On a side note, if i remember well, i think that you can directly do `joins(:authors)` to save you some typing, but you still have to use "contributors" in your where clauses.

Comment: It looks like that would be vulnerable to a SQL injection, say if `params[:authors]` is `1; DROP TABLE....`

Comment: @Noah_S Don't think so.  Unless you're doing something stupid like constructing your own where string, `params[:authors]` will be sanitized