# Rails - Query Associated Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I feel like this is rather simple, but nothing I've found seems to work. I'm using a PostgreSQL database with Rails 5. I need to run a query that finds all Products that contain a string of text in the name column or that same string is found in an associated model. Here is my model structure.

```
class NormalBrand < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :normal_models
end

class NormalModel < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :normal_brand 
    has_many :products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :normal_model
end
```

Each of the models has a field called "name". I am trying to create a query in my Products controller that finds all of the Products where the string of text is found in any of the 3 models "name" column. Something like this...

```
@products = Product.where("name like lower(?)", "%#{value}%").or.where("normal_model.name like lower(?)", "%#{value}%").or.where("normal_model.normal_brand.name like lower(?)", "%#{value}%")
```

I know the above query is completely wrong and I should have some sort of joins statement, but that's where I need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Product.joins(:normal_model).where("normal_models.name like lower(?) OR products.name like lower (?)", "%#{value}%", "%#{value}%")` try this

Answer (score 5):

Join `normal_model` and `normal_brand` and then you can query on all of three tables

```
@products = 
  Product
  .joins(normal_model: :normal_brand)
  .where("products.name like lower(?)", "%#{value}%")
  .or.where("normal_models.name like lower(?)", "%#{value}%")
  .or.where("normal_brands.name like lower(?)", "%#{value}%")
```

Or simply in one raw where

```
@products = 
  Product
  .joins(normal_model: :normal_brand)
  .where("products.name      LIKE lower(:term) OR
          normal_models.name LIKE lower(:term) OR
          normal_brands.name LIKE lower(:term)", term: "'%#{value}%'")
```

Comment: This is close to what I need, except the normal_brand is the parent of normal_model and I cannot do a joins because of that. I've posted the structure of my models in the question. Thanks

Comment: you can do nested joins clauses 
  `.joins(normal_brand: :normal_model)`

but it may need to have `has_many  :normal_models  :through =>  :normal_brands` association
This answer explains it a bit better https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528454/8088139

Comment: I'm getting this error. Can't join 'Product' to association named 'normal_brand'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: @products = Product.joins(:normal_model, :normal_brand).where("normal_models.name like UPPER(?) OR products.name like UPPER(?) OR normal_brands.name like UPPER(?)", "%#{value}%", "%#{value}%", "%#{value}%")

Comment: since it is a has_many relationship, it should be `normal_brands` not `normal_brand`

Comment: No normal model belongs to normal brand so singular

Comment: Still getting the same error. I'm positive that my model relationships are setup correctly.

Comment: Cannon - you're using `.joins(:normal_model, :normal_brand)` but you should use `.joins(normal_model: :normal_brand)`